# Terraform Cloud: How to download .tfstate file using API?

Tags: terraform-cloud, terraform-enterprise

i have deployed terraform script using Terraform Cloud.
In tab 'STATE' I can see all the data of my VM machine. For my pipeline I need to download the sv-xxxx.tfstate file in order to get the VM IP.
My question is how can I download this file using API?
I looked in documentation but couldn't find any hint.

Answer (score 2):

As the [doc](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cloud/api/state-versions.html#fetch-the-current-state-version-for-a-workspace) states, you can call
`GET /workspaces/:workspace_id/current-state-version` whose response will include a `hosted-state-download-url` attribute. This is the URL for the `.tfstate` file.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this command that I found in this tutorial: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/cloud/cloud-state-api#modify-and-create-the-state-payload

```
#!/bin/bash
HTTP_RESPONSE=$(curl \
 --header "Authorization: Bearer "$TFC_TOKEN"" \
 --header "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json" \
 "https://app.terraform.io/api/v2/workspaces/"$WORKSPACE_ID"/current-state-version" | jq -r '.data | .attributes | ."hosted-state-download-url"') 

curl -o state.tfstate $HTTP_RESPONSE
```